# Delete dynamic controls inside a Panel with dynamic Buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My code dynamically produces a Label with a white background inside of a Panel, by the click of a Button. On top of each dynamically produced Label is a red "X" Button that can be used to delete each Label.
Everything works except for that I can only delete the last Label that is created. I would like the code to delete each Label one at a time.

I know `panel1.controls.clear()` will delete everything in the Panel but I want to delete each Label individually with the delete Button produced on the Label.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim MyControls As List(Of Control)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyControls = New List(Of Control)
        Dim lblBg As New Label 
        Dim btnDelete As New Button

        lblBg.Size = New Size(230, 200)
        lblBg.Location = New Point(counter * 240, 10)
        lblBg.BackColor = Color.White
        lblBg.ForeColor = Color.Black

        btnDelete.Name = "btn" & counter
        btnDelete.Size = New Size(25, 25)
        btnDelete.Location = New Point(counter * 240, 10)
        btnDelete.BackColor = Color.White
        btnDelete.ForeColor = Color.Red
        btnDelete.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        btnDelete.Text = "x"
        btnDelete.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
        btnDelete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        AddHandler btnDelete.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick

        Panel1.Controls.Add(btnDelete)
        MyControls.Add(btnDelete)
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblBg)
        MyControls.Add(lblBg)
        counter += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        counter = 0
        For Each c As Control In MyControls
            Panel1.Controls.Remove(c)
            c.Dispose()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Any help from an experience VB programmer will be appreciated!

Comment: Assign the `Label` you just created to the `Tag` property of the `Button` you just created. In the `Click` event handler, get the `Button` from the `sender` parameter, get the `Label` from the `Tag` of the `Button` and then `Remove` them both from the `Panel`.  Don't forget to remove the event handler from the `Button`.

Comment: Also, you really ought to be using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` to position the controls automatically.  Also, you should consider designing your own user control that contains a `Label` and a `Button`.  That way, the whole unit will be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're recreating the **`List(Of Control)`** each time a new Label is created, thus the list will contain just the last Label you added.
The, when trying to remove one of the Labels, you're iterating the whole collection.  If the `List(Of Control)` was properly maintained, you'ld remove all Controls.

Btw, don't use this:

```
Panel1.Controls.Remove(c)
```

Just call `[Control].Dispose()`, you'll dispose of the object and this will also removed it from the containers' collection.

The other, more subtle, issue is the way you're positioning the controls on the Panel's container: you'll have a hard time to reposition one of the controls in the previous place (if needed) when a control is removed. Using that counter, you're only increasing the `Location.X` position.

I suggest to add a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel) to the Panel you're using to place your Controls. Place it inside the Panel, set its [Dock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock) property to **`DockStyle.Fill`**, then add your Controls to it, it will take care of their placement for you.  The Button needs to be *parented* with the Label to work correctly.
You could also create a UserControl instead of using a couple of standard controls.

Here, the Tag property of the Button is used to reference the Label it belongs to.
When the Button is clicked, the **`sender`** object will be the Button that raised the event, you just need to cast **`sender`** to **`Button`** (or `Control`) to access its properties.
The Tag property is used to dispose of the related Label.
The event handler also needs to be *un-registered*.

**Note**: the `FlowLayoutPanel` is named **`flp1`** in this code.

```
Private Sub btnAddLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddLabel.Click

    Dim lblBg As New Label() With {
        .BackColor = Color.White,
        .ForeColor = Color.Black,
        .Size = New Size(230, 200)
    }

    Dim btnDelete As New Button() With {
        .BackColor = Color.White,
        .ForeColor = Color.Red,
        .Font = New Font("Arial", 10.0!, FontStyle.Bold),
        .Location = New Point(0, 0),
        .Parent = lblBg,
        .Size = New Size(25, 25),
        .Tag = lblBg,
        .Text = "x"
    }
    btnDelete.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
    btnDelete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    AddHandler btnDelete.Click, AddressOf ButtonDeleteClick
    flp1.Controls.Add(lblBg)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonDeleteClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctrl As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    DirectCast(ctrl.Tag, Control).Dispose()
    RemoveHandler ctrl.Click, AddressOf ButtonDeleteClick
    ctrl.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: wow thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This information has been very useful to me!